# sub report text field alignment & font not working in jasper report when I run it via java code, where as it works fine in preview mode

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have main report & one subreport (I have used sub report in main reports title band), I have set some alignment & fonts for some of the text fields & static text fields. When I run it via Jasper reports Preview mode it works fine, even export is proper if I export it via preview mode.

But when I am running same .jrxml (main & sub report .jrxml) via java code, the content of main report are getting displayed proper as I want, but only the contents of sub report are not proper aligned.

Please let me know the answers, thanks in advance.

Here is the sub report xml code:

```
<title>
        <band height="92" splitType="Stretch">
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="0" y="1" width="1980" height="89" isPrintInFirstWholeBand="true" uuid="a3d62877-7e70-4ea0-8d6b-0f658e37a78d"/>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource ($P{exitMethodReport_SubReportDatasource}.getData())]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["exit_method_subreport.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </title>
```

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when you have a different (probably older) version of the Jasper library at runtime than the one you used to compile the `.jrxml` file;  resulting in markup elements in your `.jasper` file that the Jasper runtime doesn't understand.

You should either update your runtime library (recommended) or compile the report to the correct version in iReport.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I am using same version of jasper reports means 6.3.0 for both compile time & run time. But still getting an issue. Anything else that I can try for?